# Why does image disappear when using requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I draw `canvas` and add a `Plane` on it. The `canvas` and `Plane` work when I use `setInterval()`, but if I use `requestAnimationFrame()`, the `Plane` disappears. The `Plane` image is local and its position depends on the mouse position.

```
const canvas = this.refs.canvas
const contex = canvas.getContext('2d')

function DrawBoard() {
  contex.fillStyle = "black"
  contex.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 350)
}

function Plane() {
  const image1 = new Image()
  image1.src = "Plane.png"
  image1.onload = function () {
    contex.drawImage(image1, planeX - 110, planeY - 90, 200, 160);
    }
}

function Game() {
  DrawBoard()
  Plane()
}

function Animate() {
  Game()
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Animate)
}

Animate()
```

Comment: You're creating the image on every `Plane()` call, I guess you can create it after declaring canvas and use the function to place the image where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the fact that you re-loading the plane image every loop and drawing it in the `onload` handler. This will fire `async` to the `Plane()` call once the image is loaded (even if it is loaded from cache). Drawing it here means it is being drawn `async` to your render loop and you aren't controlling your draw order.

Instead, you should load the image prior to starting your rendering and re-use it throughout. E.g.:

```
const canvas = this.refs.canvas
const contex = canvas.getContext('2d')
const image1 = new Image()

function DrawBoard() {
  contex.fillStyle = "black"
  contex.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 350)
}

function Plane() {
  contex.drawImage(image1, planeX - 110, planeY - 90, 200, 160);
}

function Game() {
  DrawBoard()
  Plane()
}

function Animate() {
  Game()
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Animate)
}

// Start the animation after the plane image is loaded
image1.onload = function () {
  Animate()
}
image1.src = "Plane.png"
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem. The above solution solves the problem if you have one image. What happens if you have a bunch? @smashed-potatoes